# Kafka unable to connect to zookeeper ensemble on EKS

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, amazon-eks

I am trying to run Kafka cluster on AWS EKS cluster (v1.16). I am using bitnami helm charts.

https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/kafka
https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/zookeeper

I have deployed zookeeper ensemble successfully using below command:

```
helm install zookeeper bitnami/zookeeper --set replicaCount=3 --set auth.enabled=false --set allowAnonymousLogin=true --set persistence.storageClass=ebs --set persistence.accessModes={ReadWriteOnce} --set persistence.size=1Gi --set podLabels."app\.kubernetes\.io/version"="1.0"
```

It outputs:

```
ZooKeeper can be accessed via port 2181 on the following DNS name from within your cluster:

    zookeeper.pulse.svc.cluster.local
```

Now, I am trying to deploy Kafka cluster with below command:

```
helm install kafka bitnami/kafka --set replicaCount=3 --set zookeeper.enabled=false --set externalZookeeper.servers=zookeeper.pulse.svc.cluster.local --set autoCreateTopicsEnable=true --set persistence.storageClass=ebs --set persistence.accessModes={ReadWriteOnce} --set persistence.size=1Gi --set podLabels."app\.kubernetes\.io/version"="1.0"
```

It outputs:

```
Kafka can be accessed by consumers via port 9092 on the following DNS name from within your cluster:

    kafka.pulse.svc.cluster.local

Each Kafka broker can be accessed by producers via port 9092 on the following DNS name(s) from within your cluster:
    kafka-0.kafka-headless.pulse.svc.cluster.local
    kafka-1.kafka-headless.pulse.svc.cluster.local
    kafka-2.kafka-headless.pulse.svc.cluster.local
```

It creates 3 pods but none of the pod is able to connect to zookeeper. I am not getting what is the issue here.
Kafka pod logs:

```
2020-07-06T11:22:40.506134648Z  11:22:40.50 Welcome to the Bitnami kafka container
2020-07-06T11:22:40.507301179Z  11:22:40.50 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-kafka
2020-07-06T11:22:40.508519907Z  11:22:40.50 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-kafka/issues
2020-07-06T11:22:40.51039472Z  11:22:40.50 
2020-07-06T11:22:40.511630347Z  11:22:40.51 INFO  ==> ** Starting Kafka setup **
2020-07-06T11:22:40.55379314Z  11:22:40.55 WARN  ==> You set the environment variable ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes. For safety reasons, do not use this flag in a production environment.
2020-07-06T11:22:40.561203295Z  11:22:40.56 INFO  ==> Initializing Kafka...
2020-07-06T11:22:40.565054949Z  11:22:40.56 INFO  ==> No injected configuration files found, creating default config files
2020-07-06T11:22:40.723721499Z  11:22:40.72 INFO  ==> Configuring Kafka for inter-broker communications with PLAINTEXT authentication.
2020-07-06T11:22:40.726161543Z  11:22:40.72 WARN  ==> Inter-broker communications are configured as PLAINTEXT. This is not safe for production environments.
2020-07-06T11:22:40.727497832Z  11:22:40.72 INFO  ==> Configuring Kafka for client communications with PLAINTEXT authentication.
2020-07-06T11:22:40.731790674Z  11:22:40.73 WARN  ==> Client communications are configured using PLAINTEXT listeners. For safety reasons, do not use this in a production environment.
2020-07-06T11:22:40.73699684Z  11:22:40.73 INFO  ==> ** Kafka setup finished! **
2020-07-06T11:22:40.737001986Z 
2020-07-06T11:22:40.746297253Z  11:22:40.74 INFO  ==> ** Starting Kafka **
2020-07-06T11:22:41.512303802Z [2020-07-06 11:22:41,511] INFO Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$)
2020-07-06T11:22:42.008231959Z [2020-07-06 11:22:42,007] INFO starting (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
2020-07-06T11:22:42.009112085Z [2020-07-06 11:22:42,008] INFO Connecting to zookeeper on zookeeper.pulse.svc.cluster.local (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
2020-07-06T11:22:42.028233655Z [2020-07-06 11:22:42,028] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Initializing a new session to zookeeper.pulse.svc.cluster.local. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
2020-07-06T11:22:42.032763227Z [2020-07-06 11:22:42,032] INFO Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.5.7-f0fdd52973d373ffd9c86b81d99842dc2c7f660e, built on 02/10/2020 11:30 GMT (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2020-07-06T11:22:42.032776511Z [2020-07-06 11:22:42,032] INFO Client environment:host.name=kafka-0.kafka-headless.pulse.svc.cluster.local (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2020-07-06T11:22:42.03283528Z [2020-07-06 11:22:42,032] INFO Client environment:java.version=11.0.7 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2020-07-06T11:22:42.032984414Z [2020-07-06 11:22:42,032] INFO Client environment:java.vendor=BellSoft (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2020-07-06T11:22:42.033005091Z [2020-07-06 11:22:42,032] INFO Client environment:java.home=/opt/bitnami/java (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2020-07-06T11:22:42.03312054Z [2020-07-06 11:22:42,032] INFO Client environment:java.class.path=/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/activation-1.1.1.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/aopalliance-repackaged-2.5.0.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/argparse4j-0.7.0.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/commons-cli-1.4.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-api-2.5.0.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-basic-auth-extension-2.5.0.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-file-2.5.0.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-json-2.5.0.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-mirror-2.5.0.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-mirror-client-2.5.0.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-runtime-2.5.0.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-transforms-2.5.0.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/hk2-api-2.5.0.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/hk2-locator-2.5.0.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/hk2-utils-2.5.0.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-annotations-2.10.2.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-core-2.10.2.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-dataformat-csv-2.10.2.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.10.2.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-jaxrs-base-2.10.2.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.10.2.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.10.2.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-module-paranamer-2.10.2.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-module-scala_2.12-2.10.2.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.4.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jakarta.inject-2.5.0.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.5.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/javassist-3.22.0-CR2.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/javassist-3.26.0-GA.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.1.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-client-2.28.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-common-2.28.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-container-servlet-2.28.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-container-servlet-core-2.28.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-hk2-2.28.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-media-jaxb-2.28.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-server-2.28.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-client-9.4.24.v20191120.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-continuation-9.4.24.v20191120.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-http-9.4.24.v20191120.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-io-9.4.24.v20191120.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-security-9.4.24.v20191120.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-server-9.4.24.v20191120.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-servlet-9.4.24.v20191120.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-servlets-9.4.24.v20191120.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-util-9.4.24.v20191120.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/jopt-simple-5.0.4.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-log4j-appender-2.5.0.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-examples-2.5.0.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-scala_2.12-2.5.0.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-test-utils-2.5.0.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-tools-2.5.0.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka_2.12-2.5.0-sources.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka_2.12-2.5.0.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/lz4-java-1.7.1.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/maven-artifact-3.6.3.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-buffer-4.1.45.Final.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-codec-4.1.45.Final.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-handler-4.1.45.Final.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-resolver-4.1.45.Final.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.45.Final.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.45.Final.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/paranamer-2.8.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/plexus-utils-3.2.1.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/reflections-0.9.12.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/rocksdbjni-5.18.3.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-collection-compat_2.12-2.1.3.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-java8-compat_2.12-0.9.0.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-library-2.12.10.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-logging_2.12-3.9.2.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-reflect-2.12.10.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/snappy-java-1.1.7.3.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/zookeeper-3.5.7.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/zookeeper-jute-3.5.7.jar:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/../libs/zstd-jni-1.4.4-7.jar (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2020-07-06T11:22:42.033182063Z [2020-07-06 11:22:42,033] INFO Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2020-07-06T11:22:42.033188827Z [2020-07-06 11:22:42,033] INFO Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2020-07-06T11:22:42.03322714Z [2020-07-06 11:22:42,033] INFO Client environment:java.compiler=<NA> (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2020-07-06T11:22:42.033253354Z [2020-07-06 11:22:42,033] INFO Client environment:os.name=Linux (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2020-07-06T11:22:42.033280159Z [2020-07-06 11:22:42,033] INFO Client environment:os.arch=amd64 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2020-07-06T11:22:42.033324405Z [2020-07-06 11:22:42,033] INFO Client environment:os.version=4.14.181-140.257.amzn2.x86_64 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2020-07-06T11:22:42.033355581Z [2020-07-06 11:22:42,033] INFO Client environment:user.name=? (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2020-07-06T11:22:42.033399449Z [2020-07-06 11:22:42,033] INFO Client environment:user.home=? (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2020-07-06T11:22:42.03340494Z [2020-07-06 11:22:42,033] INFO Client environment:user.dir=/ (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2020-07-06T11:22:42.033468947Z [2020-07-06 11:22:42,033] INFO Client environment:os.memory.free=1015MB (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2020-07-06T11:22:42.033509114Z [2020-07-06 11:22:42,033] INFO Client environment:os.memory.max=1024MB (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2020-07-06T11:22:42.033536891Z [2020-07-06 11:22:42,033] INFO Client environment:os.memory.total=1024MB (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2020-07-06T11:22:42.035251257Z [2020-07-06 11:22:42,035] INFO Initiating client connection, connectString=zookeeper.pulse.svc.cluster.local sessionTimeout=18000 watcher=kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient$ZooKeeperClientWatcher$@6ee6f53 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2020-07-06T11:22:42.038953719Z [2020-07-06 11:22:42,038] INFO jute.maxbuffer value is 4194304 Bytes (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocket)
2020-07-06T11:22:42.043407452Z [2020-07-06 11:22:42,043] INFO zookeeper.request.timeout value is 0. feature enabled= (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
2020-07-06T11:22:42.045196444Z [2020-07-06 11:22:42,045] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Waiting until connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
2020-07-06T11:22:42.053941415Z [2020-07-06 11:22:42,053] INFO Opening socket connection to server zookeeper.pulse.svc.cluster.local/172.20.162.36:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
2020-07-06T11:22:42.057906383Z [2020-07-06 11:22:42,057] INFO Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /100.64.5.213:52738, server: zookeeper.pulse.svc.cluster.local/172.20.162.36:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
2020-07-06T11:22:42.061035524Z [2020-07-06 11:22:42,060] INFO Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x0, likely server has closed socket, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
2020-07-06T11:22:43.632054003Z [2020-07-06 11:22:43,631] INFO Opening socket connection to server zookeeper.pulse.svc.cluster.local/172.20.162.36:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
2020-07-06T11:22:43.632596098Z [2020-07-06 11:22:43,632] INFO Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /100.64.5.213:52756, server: zookeeper.pulse.svc.cluster.local/172.20.162.36:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
2020-07-06T11:22:43.634993004Z [2020-07-06 11:22:43,634] INFO Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x0, likely server has closed socket, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
2020-07-06T11:22:44.760870715Z [2020-07-06 11:22:44,760] INFO Opening socket connection to server zookeeper.pulse.svc.cluster.local/172.20.162.36:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
2020-07-06T11:22:44.761283232Z [2020-07-06 11:22:44,761] INFO Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /100.64.5.213:52772, server: zookeeper.pulse.svc.cluster.local/172.20.162.36:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
2020-07-06T11:22:44.763353195Z [2020-07-06 11:22:44,763] INFO Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x0, likely server has closed socket, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
2
2020-07-06T11:23:12.738834004Z [2020-07-06 11:23:12,738] INFO Session: 0x0 closed (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
2020-07-06T11:23:12.738918322Z [2020-07-06 11:23:12,738] INFO EventThread shut down for session: 0x0 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
2020-07-06T11:23:12.740751654Z [2020-07-06 11:23:12,740] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Closed. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
2020-07-06T11:23:12.745313347Z [2020-07-06 11:23:12,743] ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
2020-07-06T11:23:12.745331011Z kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING
2020-07-06T11:23:12.745335139Z  at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.$anonfun$waitUntilConnected$3(ZooKeeperClient.scala:262)
2020-07-06T11:23:12.745338245Z  at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.waitUntilConnected(ZooKeeperClient.scala:258)
2020-07-06T11:23:12.745340837Z  at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.<init>(ZooKeeperClient.scala:119)
2020-07-06T11:23:12.745343374Z  at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$.apply(KafkaZkClient.scala:1863)
2020-07-06T11:23:12.745345577Z  at kafka.server.KafkaServer.createZkClient$1(KafkaServer.scala:378)
2020-07-06T11:23:12.745347726Z  at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZkClient(KafkaServer.scala:403)
2020-07-06T11:23:12.745349947Z  at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:210)
2020-07-06T11:23:12.745352077Z  at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:44)
2020-07-06T11:23:12.745354263Z  at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:82)
2020-07-06T11:23:12.745368643Z  at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
2020-07-06T11:23:12.745806818Z [2020-07-06 11:23:12,745] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
2020-07-06T11:23:12.752833659Z [2020-07-06 11:23:12,752] INFO shut down completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
2020-07-06T11:23:12.753305908Z [2020-07-06 11:23:12,753] ERROR Exiting Kafka. (kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable)
2020-07-06T11:23:12.757961524Z [2020-07-06 11:23:12,757] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
Close
```

Also from Kafka pod machine, curl gives below o/p:

```
istio-proxy@kafka-0:/$ curl zookeeper.pulse.svc.cluster.local:2181
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
istio-proxy@kafka-0:/$
```

Note: I am having istio sidecars with mTLS disabled.

Please help.

**UPDATE**
HI,
It comes out to be the Istio porxy issue. I uninstalled Istio and it worked out.
https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-kafka/issues/38#issuecomment-451381003

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me on my local cluster.  Since you are using EKS, you are most likely using [AWS CNI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/cni-custom-network.html)(?). CNI allocates IP addresses in your VPC and if you are not allowing your security groups access to the VPC range it will not be able to access the pods. (`172.20.162.36:2181` looks like VPC address for example).

Another thing you can check if is if you have some NetworkPolicy preventing access:

```sh
kubectl get netpol
```

It's kind of odd that you get the ***expected*** response from Zookeeper:

```sh
curl zookeeper.pulse.svc.cluster.local:2181
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

So it could be possible that `zookeeper.pulse.svc.cluster.local` is resolving to an 'accessible' :2181. In any case, it looks like a firewall/network policy issue.

Comment: Thanks Rico. I dont have any netpol. It comes out to be the issue due to Istio sidecars. I have updated the answer